# Isotope, Meteor, hasClass returning false?

Tags: jquery, meteor, jquery-isotope

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.articles.rendered = function () {

    var container = $('.articles');
    var antiIso = $(container.find(".article:not(.isotope-item)"));

    if( container.children().length > 0 ) {

        if ( !container.hasClass("isotope") ) {
            console.log(container);
            console.log(container.hasClass("isotope"));

            container.isotope({
                // options
                itemSelector : '.article',
                layoutMode : 'fitRows'
            });

        } else if (container.hasClass("isotope") && antiIso.length > 0) {

            console.log("Updating Isos");

            container.isotope('addItems', antiIso, function() {
                container.isotope();
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Console Output:

```
<div class="articles isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 281px; ">…</div>
false
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here? To my understanding container should definitely have the class isotope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just realized console.log does not fully work the way I imagined, although all three times it appears that it has the class isotope console.log was showing me the end result of the object every time.

Therefore the code was acting correctly it just did not appear as though it was. Editing my code to the below fixed the issue:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.articles.rendered = function () {

    var container = $('.articles');
    var antiIso = $(container.find(".article:not(.isotope-item)"));

    if( container.children().length > 0 ) {

        if ( !container.hasClass("isotope") && antiIso ) {

            container.isotope({
                // options
                itemSelector : '.article',
                layoutMode : 'fitRows'
            });

        } else if (container.hasClass("isotope") && antiIso.length > 0) {

            console.log("Updating Isos");

            container.isotope('addItems', antiIso, function() {
                container.isotope();
            });

        }

    }

}
```